# Compress and Minify a PHP Cached Page

Tags: php, caching, compression, gzip, minify

I am using the following page caching technique as described [here](https://wesbos.com/simple-php-page-caching-technique/) and shown below:

```
<?php
$cachefile = 'cached-files/'.date('M-d-Y').'.php';
$cachetime = 18000;

// Check if the cached file is still fresh. If it is, serve it up and exit.
if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) 
{
    include($cachefile);
    exit;
}

// no file OR the file to too old, render the page and capture the HTML.
ob_start( 'ob_gzhandler' );
?>

<html>
    <!-- CONTENT GOES HERE -->
</html>

<?php
// Save the cached content to a file
$fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
fclose($fp);

// finally send browser output
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

That all works fine but I want to compress and minify the cached file.

I've added `ob_gzhandler` onto;

```
ob_start( 'ob_gzhandler' );
```

And have an htaccess file containing the following:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week”

# Fonts
  AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
  AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
  AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
  AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
  AddType image/svg+xml .svg

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-opentype image/svg+xml

  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Yet when I use any online tools to check gzip compression they all come back No. 
Am I missing something?

Is there also a way to minify the cached HTML contained in `ob_get_contents`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with what you are doing here.

Normally the Apache config you've shown us here should handle the compression - but that is dependent on the order in which the handlers are stacked. Given the complication of having to deal with generating content for the current request, the output buffer and replaying a stored file, your life will be a lot simpler if your PHP code simply ignores the compression and this is handled by the webserver. So start trying to analyse one problem at a time: look at what the webserver is responding with when you request simple PHP generated HTML. If it's not compressed then go back and have a look at your webserver (did you check if mod_delfate is actually loaded successfuly?).

> Compress and Minify a PHP Cached Page

Compression works by reducing redundancy. Minification works by reducing redundancy. Compression will reduce the size by around 80%. Unless your HTML contains a LOT of redundant tags (i.e. "`<tag></tag>`") AND your minifier is smart enough to identify and remove these (none I've seen can) OR a huge amount of whitespace, minification will only reduce the size by up to 5%. The effects are not additive.

You are adding a lot of cost (processing, programming) and complexity to your code using both and won't see any great benefit as a result.

> Is there also a way to minify the cached HTML

That would be silly.

You can't assume that clients will accept compressed content nor which compression methods they will support. You may know that all your traffic is to web browsers which support (say) gzip - but you don't know how many of them are using brain damaged AV software or some other proxy to mediate the connection. So if you maintain the cached representation compressed you need to re-implement the logic around detecting the client capability and allow for decompression in your code.

That the naming schema only accomodates a singe page/cache file rather suggests that you don't have a huge amount of data to store in your serverside cache, and disk space is cheap. Store the cache data uncompressed.

> ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

This is, at best, redundant.

> $cachefile = 'cached-files/'.date('M-d-Y').'.php';

You could have a huge security issue here if you are not being really careful to prevent XSS - an XSS vulnerability can be used as a remote code injection exploit on your server.

> include($cachefile);

If you know that the file *should* only contain HTML then why are you asking PHP to parse/compile/execute it? In addition to the security issue it creates a processing overhead and will cause your opcode cache to keep filling up and resetting.

There's also a risk of someone corrupting your cache by pulling the plug on the request before the cache file is written.

Consider:

```
 <?php
 ignore_user_abort(1);
 ...
 if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) 
 {
     while (ob_get_level()) ob_end_flsuh();
     readfile($cachefile);
     exit;
 }
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me on this and with such in-depth info. Very much appreciated. I had not realised there was a potential XXS vulnerability there which is the biggest concern outside of compression/minifying. The cached file will always be HTML only. Your last code snippet which uses readFile over include - `while (ob_get_level()) ob_end_flush(); readfile($cachefile); ...` how far will that go in preventing XSS?

Comment: It doe nothing to prevent XSS (cross site scripting)  - using include() rather readfile() means that if there *is* an XSS vulnerability, it can be exploited to run code on your server.

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy to solve your problem. I also had the same problem, for this you have to anticipate the compression method to the cachefil funtion, your repaired code would look like this

```
<?php

    /* importat */
 ob_start ('ob_gzhandler');

 /* importat */ 

    $ cachefile = 'cached-files /'. date ('M-d-Y'). '. php';
    $ cachetime = 18000;

    // Check if the cached file is still fresh. If it is, serve it up and exit`enter code here`.
    if (file_exists ($ cachefile) && time () - $ cachetime <filemtime ($ cachefile))
    {
         include ($ cachefile);
         exit;
    }

    // no file OR the file to too old, render the page and capture the HTML.

    ?>

    <html>
         <! - CONTENT GOES HERE ->
    </html>

    <? php
    // Save the cached content to a file
    $ fp = fopen ($ cachefile, 'w');
    fwrite ($ fp, ob_get_contents ());
    fclose ($ fp);

    // finally send browser output

?>
```

you're welcome greetings